# Salesforce DX Usage with Classic and team work using scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, developer-console, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, development-mode

We are currently using Salesforce Classic and we have developers outside of United states using the remote desktops to login to the client machine and then using SF.

I have seen the seminars for SFDX, I also know what it is and how it works and can be used using the VS Code. I have also completed the trailhead modules on SFDX, I am aware of the scratch org concept too. I still do not have clear real world view of how SFDX can be utilize to its best. So, I have a few questions and difficulty in understanding the scratch org and other features like,

1. When we create a scratch org from a dev org to work on a specific feature, does it have all the configs from the PROD environment? Is it exactly like cloning a sandbox?
2. How best to use VS Code and Version control with SFDX in Classic? As in, What is the ideal workflow to follow while using the SFDX with VS Code and SF Classic?
3. Using SFDX, does the debugging become much easier in VS Code or is it still a but challenging? I am currently using MavensMate with VS Code but it is not the ideal flow. Not as good as SFDX.(Even though they have stopped supporting, it works best so far).

Hope to learn something which I could not learn from the trailhead modules and real world usage of SFDX and how you all use it to increase the productivity of your team?

Answer (score 3):

> When we create a scratch org from a dev org to work on a specific feature, does it have all the configs from the PROD environment? Is it exactly like cloning a sandbox?

No. It has whatever configuration you set in the appropriate configuration file. You are required make sure it contains the correct settings for whatever you're trying to develop.

> How best to use VS Code and Version control with SF Dx in Classic? As in, What is the ideal workflow to follow while using the SFDx with VS Code and SF Classic?

It's the same for all other flows. Git branching is complicated, so you'll want to do some research. Basically, "branch", "commit", "push", "merge", but there are a lot of subtleties. Make sure you experiment before starting a serious attempt.

> Using SFDx, does the debugging become much easier in VS Code or is it still a but challenging? I am currently using MavensMate with VS Code but it is not the ideal flow. Not as good as SFDx.(Even thought they have stopped supporting, it works best so far).

There's a new [Apex Replay Debugger](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/apex/replay-debugger) that can make debugging easier. Installing the bundle should give you everything you need to get started.

Comment: thanks. About the configuration file, usually if we have to develop a feature most of the times we need some of the previous configs to be able to work on top of it. So in this case, the scratch orgs doesn't have all the object and code from the sandbox we created scratch org?

Is there sort of a workflow you can possibly share or point me to a right direction where I can find a little more on how it is being used in real world? Because version controlling with Salesforce has always been a little challenging and messy sort of. Just want to understand right way of people use it.

Comment: @apple123 You have to "push" your config to the scratch org. It's not too hard, but neither is it automatic.

Comment: So basically everytime I create a scratch org, I need to push my previous configs manually even though those object and features exist in the previous sandbox? Sorry I am just a little confused. I was in an impression that cloning a sandbox and creating a scratch should be same as then only you can work on incremental changes for upcoming feature development, NO?

Comment: @apple123 No, sandboxes and scratch orgs are two different things. It's also a completely different way of development. Either way, you will do incremental changes, but the process is different.

Comment: ok, I need to get more info on what is the basic setting and configuration the scratch orgs has.. because for incremental development that matters a lot. If confis are not there you just end up spending more time in beingning them in sync in the first place.

Comment: @sfdxfox can you explain a little on the different development process, I understand creating scratch orgs and pushing the changes from one org to other and keeping version control but how do you get your scratch orgs up and running?

Comment: @apple123 The process would typically be a script, but basically `force:org:create`, `force:source:push`, `force:data:tree:import`, then do development. There might be other processes involved based on needs, but that would be the simple basics.

Comment: @sfdxfox If we enable the SFDX in Prod then only it becomes available across all sandboxes right? Does it have any implication on the current development process? Most of our devs are just using Dev Console for now, it will continue to work as it is right? Apart from not being able to disable it, is there any other implication?

Comment: @apple123 Dev Hub is for *scratch orgs* and *unlocked packages* (2GP). There's no requirement to enable Dev Hub or 2GP to use DX. As long as the user has the appropriate permissions (e.g. Author Apex), DX will work as expected. Developer Console is unaffected by enabling any of the new features.

Comment: @sfdxfox oh so if I want to develop lightning component using the VS Code and other debugging features of Dx, I do not need to enable the devhub?

Comment: Because from what I am learning, it requires DevHub to be enabled to be able to add users to SFDX.

Comment: @apple123 No, you need to enable Dev Hub to add the permission for Scratch Orgs and 2GP. You do not need any permissions more than what's required to run Developer Console to use all of the other DX commands.

Comment: @apple123 I think you're getting confused somewhere. I would suggest asking a new question about where you're specifically stuck, what you've tried, any resources you've researched etc.